# How to Automate web services using JMETER?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, javascript, web-service, json

How to Automate web services using JMETER?

I need to check URL links are working and image are loading properly and with the response code given.

see more details in below example, i just want to check that highlighted links(blue color) are working fine through jmeter.

just think this is web service url -> https://api.github.com/users/lrei

```
{
  "login": "lrei",
  "id": 35857,
  "avatar_url": "**https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/35857?v=3**",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "**https://api.github.com/users/lrei**",
  "html_url": "**https://github.com/lrei**",
  "followers_url": "**https://api.github.com/users/lrei/followers**",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lrei/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "Luis Rei",
  "company": null,
  "blog": "http://luisrei.com",
  "location": null,
  "email": "me@luisrei.com",
  "hireable": null,
  "bio": null,
  "public_repos": 31,
  "public_gists": 3,
  "followers": 36,
  "following": 2,
  "created_at": "2008-11-21T14:48:42Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-01-04T05:43:28Z"
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what exactly it is that you are looking for? JMeter is a performance testing tool and your description of the question suggests that you are looking to do a functionality or link testing!

Comment: @TESTasy                                                                                                                 i have updated issue description could you please look in to this?

Comment: Found no references to the images in the provided `json`?

Comment: @Rao  this is image ->  https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/35857?v=3

Comment: I meant that where in the json has the reference to the images. Haven't found any keys related to that.

Answer (score 2):

- Use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to perform initial call to the web service endpoint. You may also need to have [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header
- Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to extract the above URLs and convert them into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Use JMeter Variables in the following HTTP Request samplers to check the URLs. Response code can be verified using i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

I wouldn't recommend using Selenium for API testing as using browser it will be very tricky to send HTTP requests other than GET and manipulate request body and headers. Check out [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information on web services load testing

Answer (score 1):

As I understood that, your requirement is to test URLs and their status codes. For this, you does not require jmeter. Even if you want to test in jmeter then you need to follow below steps,

1. Create a test plan
2. Add a HTTP Sampler and configure the web service URL
3. Add a Post Processor and collect the required info and save it into variables
4. For checking the URLs and images, create separate  samplers and add assertions as per your requirement.

I suggest, as per your requirement, you can use Selenium/java. Please review the below attached link [API Automation link](http://restservicestesting.blogspot.in/)

I hope my answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri T @TESTasy  @QAMember @Rao

I have created Jmeter test plan see in below, and now i want to check the urls marked in red arrow(which are in json response). how is it possible to check them are working fine with response assertions?? could please show me as by getting this example?

[image]

## =====================================================

[image: After adding JSON extractor and Debug Sampler avatar_url=https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/35857?v=3 shown like below, but i want to check that this url working properly or not does it check according to this way?]

Comment: Now add a JSON Extractor after HTTP Request enter "$.html_url" in JSON Path Expressions. Create another Http Request and add this variable to it.

Comment: May be this link will helpful for you http://charithaka.blogspot.in/2014/05/handling-json-responses-in-apache-jmeter.html

Comment: Hi @QAMember see above screen i updated i want to check yellow highlighted url is working fine or not(by clicking) is it checking in that Debug sampler?

Comment: checking means, what you want to check in that url ??

Comment: @QAMember i want to check that this url is loading properly or not giving 404 or not crashing.. so..on is it possible to check?

Comment: for that u need to use JsonPostProcessor and get that url and save into variable.After that create a HttpRequest and pass that varaible in HttpRequest. For checking, add assertions to it

Comment: @QA member  when  you passing variable  in to http request, how to pass this variable in http request server name field or path field? URL is including / (slash)[ex variable abc= https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/35857?v=3]